# Strict aliasing rule in C

Tags: c, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

I'm trying to understand strict aliasing rule as defined in `6.5(p6)`:

> If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an
>   lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of
>   the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access
>   and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value.

and `6.5(p7)`:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:88)
>
> — a type compatible the effective type of the object

Consider the following example:

```
struct test_internal_struct_t{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct test_struct_t{
    struct test_internal_struct_t tis;
};

int main(){
    //alocated object, no declared type
    struct test_struct_t *test_struct_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*test_struct_ptr)); 

    //object designated by the lvalue has type int
    test_struct_ptr->tis.a = 1; 

    //object designated by the lvalue has type int
    test_struct_ptr->tis.b = 2; 

    //VIOLATION OF STRICT ALIASING RULE???
    struct test_internal_struct_t tis = test_struct_ptr->tis; 
    return 0;
}
```

The `malloc(sizeof(*test_struct_ptr))` has no declared type, since it is allocated, as footnote 87:

> 87) Allocated objects have no declared type

The objects accessing via `test_struct_ptr->tis.a` and `test_struct_ptr->tis.b` has *effective type* to be `int`. But the object `test_struct_ptr->tis` has no effective type since it is allocated.

**QUESTION:** Is `struct test_internal_struct_t tis = test_struct_ptr->tis;` a violation of strict aliasing? Object designated by `test_struct_ptr->tis` has no effective type, but `lvalue` has type `struct test_internal_struct_t`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see any aliasing here. There is a copy but that's not an "aliasing thing".

Comment: @4386427 Yes, the copying occurs if `test_struct_ptr->tis` is assigned to a variable. But the thing that confused me was that there were no stores involving lvalue `test_struct_ptr->tis`, but `test_struct_ptr->tis.a` and `test_struct_ptr->tis.b` were. So the object designated by the `test_struct_ptr->tis` has no effective type (allocated), but the lvalue itself has type `struct test_internal_struct_t`. It is most likely that I understood the wording of these sections incorrectly...

Comment: @4386427 The footnote `87)` is especially confusing. So any `malloc`ed object has no effective type until we assign to it using some `lvalue` expression.

Comment: But you do assign to it … and then you copy the whole struct to **another** memory area (with automatic storage duration). That can never be related to aliasing.

Comment: @4386427 But `6.5(p7)` specifies rules for accessing. Percisely _An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types — a type compatible the effective type of the object_. I thought that statement `struct test_internal_struct_t tis = test_struct_ptr->tis;` involves "accessing" in the sense of `6.5(p7)`.

Comment: To me your question is unclear (sorry). It seems to me your question is not about strict aliasing. Instead it seems be whether it is **legal to access the allocated memory** using `test_struct_ptr->tis` when the initialisation has been done by initialising the individual members (e.g. `test_struct_ptr->tis.a = 1;`). If that is the question then the answer is *yes, it is legal* - no problem. In any case - there is not any aliasing here.

Comment: @4386427: OP’s point is they store an `int` and another `int` and then read a `struct test_internal_struct_t`. So how did the allocated memory come to have an effective type of `struct test_internal_struct_t`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil But those `int`s are members of the struct so access to the whole struct using `test_struct_ptr->tis` is fine. Once the memory is accessed using the pointer `test_struct_ptr` the effective type is `struct test_struct_t` - nothing is being aliased here.

Comment: @4386427: You say “Once the memory is accessed using the pointer `test_struct_ptr`…. But the object is never actually accessed via the pointer, in the most literal sense. `test_struct_ptr` is used only as the left operand of `->`, where it serves as an lvalue that is never converted to a value or used as the operand of an assignment or other operation that modifies the object. Rather, it is only used with `->` to produce an lvalue for a member, and it is only that member’s lvalue, or a further member reference with `.`, that is actually used directly to access the memory.

Comment: @4386427: I have encountered this distinction previously, and it is a shortcoming in the C standard that it fails to be explicit about what it means to store a value “through an lvalue”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil see the ANSI C rationale why struct aliasing rule was introduced https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/c3.html#3-3. It is more than clear what "store through an lvalue" means. It is applicable to the left-hand operand of the assignment (or a compound assignment) operator, and not to every lvalue subexpression of that operand as you are trying to convince everyone.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: If that were true, the aliasing rule would fail to accomplish its purpose, as the optimizer could never determine that accesses to members of `struct A` were not accesses to members of incompatible but identically laid out `struct B`.

Comment: @SomeName http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_219.htm may be relevant here. Esp. «_The objects resulting from the calls to memcpy may also be accessed by other types (primarily given by Subclause 6.5 paragraph 7)._» You don't have calls to memcpy, but the situation is similar: objects with effective types of struct members are created, but the whole struct haven't been copied.

Comment: @EricPostpischil objects of types `struct A` and `struct B` are either "visible" to an optimizer and it is clear that they are not overlapping or, if there are only pointers to `struct A` and `struct B` it is enough to know that the Standard only guarantees that pointer to `struct A` can be casted to pointer to `struct B` and **back**. It does not guarantee that this pointer can be used otherwise. E.g. to access a member of `struct B`. So the optimizer can safely assume that objects pointed to do not overlap. No need to rely on strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Assuming you are correct that a `struct a *A` cannot be converted to a `struct b *B` and then used to access objects, there are other ways to derive a `struct a *` and a `struct b *` that point to the same memory without converting between them. Most obviously, given `void *x = malloc(…)`, we may define `struct a *A = x` and `struct b *B = x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C 2018 6.5 6 defines *effective type* using the phrase “stored … through an lvalue” but never defines that phrase:

> If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value.

So it is left to readers to interpret. Consider this code:

```
struct a { int x; };
struct b { int x; };

void copy(int N, struct a *A, struct b *B)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        A[n].x = B[n].x;
}
```

If the compiler knows that the various objects `A[n]` do not overlap the various objects `B[n]`, then it can optimize this code by performing a load of several `B[n]` in one instruction (such as an AVX or other single-instruction multiple-data [SIMD] instruction) and storing several `A[n]` in one instruction. (This may require additional code to handle loop fragment and alignment issues. Those do not concern us here.) If it is possible that some `A[n]->x` might refer to the same object as a `B[n]->x` for a different value of `n`, then the compiler may not use such multi-element loads and stores, as it could change the observable behavior of the program.  For example, if the situation were that memory contained ten `int` with values from 0 to 9 and `B` pointed to the 0 while `A` pointed to the 2:

```
B   A
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Then the loop as written, given `N` = 4, must copy the elements one at a time, producing:

```
0 1 0 1 0 1 6 7 8 9
```

If the compiler optimized this to four-element loads and stores, it could load 0 1 2 3 and then store 0 1 2 3, producing:

```
0 1 0 1 2 3 6 7 8 9
```

However, C tells us that `struct a` and `struct b` are incompatible, even though they are laid out identically. When types `X` and `Y` are incompatible, it tells us that an `X` is not a `Y`. A significant purpose of the type system is to distinguish object types.

Now consider the expression `A[n]->x = B[n]->x`. In this:

- `A[n]` is an lvalue for a `struct a`.
- Since `A[n]` is the left operand of a `.`, it is not converted to a value.
- `A[n].x` designates and is an lvalue for the member `x` of `A[n]`.
- The value of the right operand replaces the value in `A[n].x`.

So, the direct access to an object that stores a value is solely in the `int` that is the member `A[n].x`. The lvalue `A[n]` appears in the expression, but it is not the lvalue used directly to store a value. What is the effective type of the memory at `&A[n]`?

If we interpret this memory as merely an `int`, then the only restriction on the object accesses is that all the `B[n].x` are `int` and all the `A[n].x` are `int`, so some or all of the `A[n].x` may access the same memory as some or all of the `B[n].x`, and the compiler is not permitted to make the optimization described above.

This does not serve the purpose of the type system to distinguish `struct a` and `struct b`, and so it cannot be a correct interpretation. To enable the intended optimization, it must be that the memory stored by `A[n].x` contains `struct a` objects, and the memory accessed by `B[n].x` contains `struct b` objects.

Therefore, “stored … through an lvalue” must include expressions where an lvalue is used to derive members of structures but is not itself the final lvalue used for access.

Comment: Since allocated objects have no declared type what object do? Ones that has anything but allocated storage duration?

Comment: @SomeName: Ordinary declarations declare types for their objects: For example, `int a[3]` declares `a` to be an array of 3 `int`.